# How to have separate thread serving each cliet request in DCOM

Tags: winapi, com, dcom

I would like to write one com SERVER in such a way so that each new client request to this com server should be served by separate thread.

So far I have created one sample MTA out of proc COM server, but what I observe when I make a com function call is..

1. this pointer is separate in a com function call(i.e. each cocreateinstance is creating separate com object)
2. if I print GetCurrentThreadID() in the COM function, then it gives same value for each of my client.

it means there is only one com thread serving all of my client requests.

please advice how we can separate thread for every client. I can afford multiple running exe of the same com server.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: Forcing a local server to serve distinct threads per client is not something I've tried, nor can I imagine it is possible. You can easily force a separate *process* for each client. See [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/8a80bf87-57fc-4439-a8f4-7308a58b02de/how-to-force-a-dcom-server-to-launch-a-new-process-versus-a-thread) for info on one way to do it. I'm curious myself if it is possible to keep a single local server while having guaranteed-distinct separate RPC-threads handling client requests; almost as curious as I am for why you *need* this in the first place.

Comment: Thanks for you answer..I am OK with having multiple exe of the same COM server serving each of my client.  I have seen the link which you have shared with me, but got confused..I have created my COm using VS2008 ATL wizard, but not getting where do I need to define RegisterClassObjects function in my coclass..please help

Comment: Below mention is code for my WinMain function    CoInitializeEx( NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED );
  HRESULT hr ;
  hr = _AtlModule.RegisterClassObjects(CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, REGCLS_MULTI_SEPARATE );
  OutputDebugString(L"resut is "+_bstr_t(hr));
 return _AtlModule.WinMain(nShowCmd);

Comment: For an MTA server, COM runtime would generally create a thread pool for serving incoming requests. If multiple method calls come in simultaneously, then they would be served on different threads. But if they come one after another - whether from different clients or otherwise - then it's normal and expected that they would be served by the same thread.